# Adding Rows of new data to an existing dataset (forecast) and I get error number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Tags: arrays, r, forecasting

I have a dataset with 3 variables, and then I ran a VAR(2) and got the forecast for it. Now I simply want to 'add' the forecast results to the original data, however, I don't seem to be able to get cbind to work (I looked into merge and attached but I don't get them.

So, how do I simply include the forecast with my original dataset?

What I have is:

```
        data(Model)                    #which is my dataset with data
1980:Q2 to 2014:Q2 [dates are my rows and then I have 3 columns)
        library(MTS)                   #the package I am using to get VAR
    V2= VAR(usmacro, p=2)              #running the VAR(2)
    FC2=VARpred(model=V2, h=4)         #running forecast
```

Now I am trying to add the prediction results from FC2 to my 'Model' original data.

My FC2 output is:

```
       sho   tan    tba
[1,] 3.688 1.498 0.1272
[2,] 3.952 1.625 0.3119
Standard Errors of predictions:  
      [,1]  [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 3.520 1.519 0.6391
[2,] 3.704 1.743 0.9873
Root mean square errors of predictions:  
      [,1]  [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 3.566 1.539 0.6474
[2,] 4.804 2.861 2.2302
```

Now I tried:

```
Fc2=data.frame(FC2)     #turn output into a dataframe
FC3=Fc2[,(1:3)]         # with this line I am extracting only the first  3 columns I want
NewModel=cbind(Model,FC3)  #this should give me the new matrix, just with the three new rows added at the end.
```

However, when I run this I get the following error: 
Warning message:
In cbind(usmacro, VP22) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

My Model data (tail) shows:

```
[264,]  2.705383 1.433774 0.09
[265,]  1.750523 1.068212 0.05
[266,]  4.418425 1.630659 0.03
[267,]  3.439430 1.411608 0.06
[268,] -2.130694 1.328627 0.05
[269,]  3.874164 1.964367 0.03
```

I just want to add these prediction rows to the model data as row 270 and 271.

```
[1,] 3.688 1.498 0.1272
[2,] 3.952 1.625 0.3119
```

Any advice on how to make this work?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve, but if you just want to add those 2 rows to your Model data, just use `rbind`

Comment: As @DominicComtois pointed out, you are surely confusing `cbind` ("c" for columns) and `rbind` ("r" for rows).

Comment: Thanks, I used rbind but originally couldn't get it to work. I just ried again I realized I have to rename the columns of the second set to be the same of the first and then it works. Sorry, beginner error. thanks!